# How to check if one or more columns exist in dataset

Tags: r, if-statement

How can I check if my dataset contains all the columns needed to perform calculations? I can check  succesfully for one column but when I add another column to check I get a message saying that only the first column will be evaluated. What is the most efficient way to accomplish this? I got this code and attempt below:

```
   wk month         xd         td        pd year
1   1     1 0.03700988 0.02701157  317.3084 2007
2   1     1 0.03912160 0.02841586    0.0000 2007
3   1     1 0.04098652 0.02965604  126.7196 2007
4   1     1         NA         NA        NA 2007
5   1     1         NA         NA        NA 2007
6   1     1         NA         NA        NA 2007
7   1     1         NA         NA        NA 2007
8   2     1 0.01518800 0.01250000 2671.6000 2007
9   2     1 0.00751300 0.00739600 3540.6977 2007
10  2     1 0.01271600 0.01085600 1270.3574 2007
11  2     1 0.01396200 0.01168500 1067.6936 2007
12  2     1 0.01425900 0.01188200  688.0996 2007
13  2     1 0.02355300 0.01806300  317.4445 2007
14  2     1 0.03212200 0.02376100  420.9419 2007
15  3     1 0.03953000 0.02868700  280.4755 2007
16  3     1 0.02894600 0.02164900  250.6813 2007
17  3     1 0.03076900 0.02286100  159.0482 2007
18  3     1 0.03081500 0.02289200  258.1251 2007
19  3     1 0.02918700 0.02180900  450.8689 2007
20  3     1 0.02260400 0.01743200    0.0000 2007
21  3     1 0.02892000 0.02163200  120.8395 2007

#Data
a <- structure(list(wk = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), month = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), xd = c(0.0370098838217444, 
0.0391215970961887, 0.0409865246890313, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.015188, 
0.007513, 0.012716, 0.013962, 0.014259, 0.023553, 0.032122, 0.03953, 
0.028946, 0.030769, 0.030815, 0.029187, 0.022604, 0.02892), td = c(0.02701157274146, 
0.0284158620689655, 0.0296560389182058, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0125, 
0.007396, 0.010856, 0.011685, 0.011882, 0.018063, 0.023761, 0.028687, 
0.021649, 0.022861, 0.022892, 0.021809, 0.017432, 0.021632), 
    pd = c(317.308439683869, 0, 126.719553152898, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 2671.6, 3540.6976744186, 1270.35740604274, 1067.69362430466, 
    688.099646524154, 317.444499806234, 420.941879550524, 280.475476696762, 
    250.681324772507, 159.048160622895, 258.125109208457, 450.868907331836, 
    0, 120.83949704142), year = c(2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 
    2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 
    2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
a

#Delete first two columns to test
a <- a[,c(3:6)]
names(a)

missing <- c("wk","month")
if (missing %in% colnames(a)) {
  #print("column Exists")
} else {
  stop("columns are missing") #I want R to stop executing any code below
}

#More code.....
```

Comment: `any(!missing %in% colnames(a))` would be TRUE if any of the specified columns are missing. In this case both columns in `missing` are missing.

Comment: With your code I get that the columns exist even though they don't exist @JonSpring

Comment: I think this is what you want, but the result is confusing given your name `missing` for columns that are required to exist. I am testing if any of the columns in `missing` do not exist, and neither do, so we get TRUE and TRUE. `any()` tests if any of the arguments are true, and in this case both are true since both columns are missing.

Comment: Got you. I am re-reruning again. One thing I noticed though is that `stop` doesn't stop the script, it continues executing even though the condition is true that columns are missing. Is that a normal behavior of `'stop` or there is another way to halt the execution of code below stop?

Answer (score 1):

Before you use a name for an object, you should first check whether there is a function with this name. Here, `missing()` is a function that can be used for unspecified arguments, hence it's very confusing to read your current code. You can simply type the name into the console (without parentheses).

```
> missing
function (x)  .Primitive("missing")
```

Apparently it's a function, otherwise we would get  `Error: object 'missing' not found`, so use something different. Now to your question.

In an `if`-`else` block, begin by evaluating `if` there are specific conditions, with the general case addressed in the `else` block thereafter.

The output within the `if()` parentheses should have length 1. For multiple conditions, functions such as `all()` or `any()` can be utilized to aggregate the conditions into a single logical value.

Since you have specified "*if* my data set contains *all* required columns" (my emphasis) as the general scenario, the inverse, expressed by `if (!all(...))` (not all) is the specific condition you want to check.

```
need <- c("wk", "month")
if (!all(need %in% colnames(a))) {
  stop("columns are missing") 
} else {
  message("column Exists")
  ## do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @jay.sf . One thing I noticed is that the condition is TRUE and the columns are missing from the dataframe, the code continues to run after `stop`. I put the following following below the last curly bracket: `print("I didn't stop");
b <- 3+3; b`